# No response on remote reboot or shutdown

Tags: 18.04, reboot

Until recently I was using

```
 sudo reboot now
```

after some system upgrade.  Now the server responds (just freezes but can be set free by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd>) neither to `reboot now` nor `shutdown -r now`.  How can I fix this?

My installation is 18.04.3 LTS, 4.15.0-66-generic x86_64

Comment: Check `dmesg` for useful log.

Comment: I would `whereis reboot` to ensure you're running the code you should and not something someone has put in /usr/local/bin/ or something; ensure the binary is valid (possibly), then see if `init` or `systemctl` also cannot boot/shutdown system... I'm not actually sure where I'd end up (for fix), but I'd explore more than you've done.

Answer (score 6):

Almost the same, for me:

```
sudo systemctl --force --force reboot
```

Worked perfectly.

Here's a good explanation about that.

https://blog.kerus.net/1897/systemctl-force-force-reboot

Answer (score 3):

Solved thanks to the hint by guiverc.  systemctl reboot gives more insight

```
Failed to set wall message, ignoring: Connection timed out
Failed to reboot system via logind: Connection timed out
```

Finally I managed to do it by

```
sudo systemctl reboot -ff
```